# Angular directive test expects service object and throws reference error

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-directives, angular-test

I tried to fake/mock the KModalService in order to pass it inside the directive but I'm just not sure how to approach the solution. In my service, once I`m no longer on the page where the component is, I destroy the component and empty the ID that I'm trying to get from the service, it might be that? any ideas?

```js
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */
import { ModalClickDirective } from './modalClickDirective.directive';

describe('Directive: ModalClickDirective', () => {

  let testBedService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        KModalModule
      ],
      providers: [KModalService]
    });

    testBedService = TestBed.get(KModalService);
  });

  it('should create an instance', () => {
    inject([KModalService], (injectService: KModalService) => {
      expect(injectService).toBe(testBedService);
      const directive = new ModalClickDirective(testBedService); // <= Here it fails
      expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
});
```

Error

```
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ModalClickDirective' before initialization
```

Directive

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[kModalClickEvent]'
})
export class ModalClickDirective implements OnInit {

  modalId: string;
  constructor(private modalService: KModalService) {
  }

   ngOnInit() {}

  @HostListener('click')
    onMouseClick() {
      this.modalId = this.modalService.tempModalId;
      const isOpen = this.modalService.getIsOpen(this.modalId);
      if (isOpen) {
        this.modalService.setIsOpen(this.modalId, false);
      } else {
        this.modalService.setIsOpen(this.modalId, true);
      }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why this error exists.

Comment: Can you share the source code of ModalClickDirective? I believe you are injecting some service classes in the construtor of ModalClickDirective component. If that's the case, then you can't initialize the class with a no-argument constructor.

Comment: @Shravan I updated the post with the Directive & the updated attempt to solve the issue, but the problem still exists.